# Empty the cache for a whole site via ASP.NET / JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, browser-cache

Is it possible to force the browser to clear the cache for a whole site/domain?
I've an ASP.NET Application and after some changes in the user-settings, all pages must be reloaded from the server next time and not from the browser's cache. Thus, can I tell the browser to clear the cache for my site?
In all other cases, the browser's cache is very useful reducing the http traffic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Check-it Out:**

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now);
Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching();
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Comment: How could that help? This just says you should not cache this specific piece of content this one time... The OP is asking to clear the existing cache.